# Material Ui box on change doesnt work with color change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Only recently started learning material UI but the box underline stopped working when navigating. is it because my links are to the singular page or did I manage to change something?  tldr loss of functionality using colored tabs props

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";
import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

function Header() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    
    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };
    
    return (
        <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }} style={{position: 'fixed'}} >
            <Tabs id="header" 
                value={value} 
                onChange={handleChange}
                textColor="secondary"
                indicatorColor="secondary"
                aria-label="secondary tabs example"
                
            >
                <a href="#about"><Tab sx={{ color: "#FEA47F"}} value={0} label="About"/></a>
                <a href="#experience"><Tab sx={{ color: "#FEA47F"}} value={1} label="Experience" /></a>
                <a href="#projects"><Tab sx={{ color: "#FEA47F"}} value={2} label="Projects" /></a>
                <a href="#contact"><Tab sx={{ color: "#FEA47F"}} value={3} label="Contact" /></a>
            </Tabs> 
        </Box>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Tried unchanging the colors and resetting to default but was still getting the same issue, I was having issues describing the problem to look it up so would be best to ask on here and show my code. It should be functioning the same as https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/ the colored tabs section and tried to follow the customization rules from here https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/